# vscode refuse to recognize my NodeJs module (intellisense) error ts(2307), however, module works just fine

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

After hours of googling, I just have no other idea :)
VSCode (1.18.61) just refuses to recognize my custom NodeJs module (I am on Windows 10)

[image]

As you can see, internal NodeJs modules like 'path' is recognized just fine.

My module package.json

```
{
  "name": "my_test_module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "just a test module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

My module index.js is horrible simple

```
class Test {

}
   
module.exports = new Test();
```

So basically NodeJs is working fine, I am able to see & use my module.
Just VSC ignores it for some reason.

I have in my global path, none of them appears to work (including after reboot)

```
%AppData%\Roaming\npm\  
%AppData%\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ 
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\
%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\
C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

Also I have checked VSC settings related to TS, however, I specifically marked JavaScript as language.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!